# Can I set hostname as a DNS Alias?

Tags: dns, hostname

I'd like to make a local machine available (for domain network) through a www address.

To do so I though I could use our DNS and set an alias like www. => MACHHINENAME.

Can it be done that way?

Comment: When you say available through WWW is that machine running a web server that will accept http(s) packets?

Comment: Yes, it's an IIS server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You have to use the CNAME record type for this. The record should look like this:

```
www.yourdomain.com IN CNAME webserver.yourdomain.com.
```

Check your DNS server administration manual on how to set this up.

Comment: webserver.yourdomain.com. is not a machine name. A mahcine name is something like MTAK-Win764. You get it with the msdos command "hostname"

Comment: It *is* a machine name, depending on what you have configured... And I don't think you said anything about Windows.